Rank of Curve25519 lifted to $\mathbb{Q}$
Curve25519 has the well-known equation
$E: y^2 = x^3 + 486662x^2 + x$
which is normally considered over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, for $p = 2^{255}-19$.
We can lift $E/\mathbb{F}_p$ to $E/\mathbb{Q}$.
According to pari gp the lift has rank 1 (lower and upper bound both 1).
Is it feasible to compute a generator for the infinite part of $E/\mathbb{Q}$?
I ask because all the coefficients here are 'small'.
This is not a question about cryptography, it's purely out of mathematical curiosity.  I think I did try this once in Magma and couldn't find a generator, but I am no expert in descent.
[EDIT]  Sagemath and pari don't have the necessary machinery to find generators of some curves.  Magma has some chance in this case, but I couldn't get it to produce a generator.
I carried out a 4-descent in Magma:
E:=EllipticCurve([0,486662,0,1,0]);
c4:=FourDescent(E);
_,qi1:=IsQuadricIntersection(c4[4]);

This gives four four-coverings, e.g. one of them is the pair of quadrics:
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & -6 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 7 & -10 \\
0 & 0 & -10 & -22
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & -17 & 0 & 0 \\
-17 & 66 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -88 & 23 \\
0 & 0 & 23 & -52
\end{bmatrix}$
I searched for a point on this with
pts:=PointsQI(c4[4],1000000000);

which turned up nothing.  So if there is a rational point on Curve25519 of infinite order, the generator might be quite large.

Try using Sagemath

You found a point using decent (well done!). One should mention that in rank 1 you always win with Heegner points (though precision/memory may become an issue in practice)

Thanks @Mummytheturkey.  My experience on math.stackexchange.com has been very strange so far, being downvoted for no reason, perfectly valid questions being closed.  At least this generator speaks for itself.

I found a point of infinite order on the lift!
Six descent in Magma did it.  The code was roughly:
SetClassGroupBounds("GRH");
E:=EllipticCurve([0,486662,0,1,0]);
time c2,phi1:=TwoDescent(E);
time c3,phi2:=ThreeDescent(E);
c6,psi1:=SixDescent(c2[1],c3[1]);
time pts6 := PointSearch(c6, 1000000000);pts;
pts3:=psi1(pts6[1]);
P1:=phi2[1](pts3);

There were 15 two-covers and Magma returns them in random order, so you might need to adapt c2[1] above.
Here is a point of infinite order on the lift of Curve25519 to $\mathbb{Q}$, in a pari-gp verification script:
e1=ellinit([0,486662,0,1,0]);
[x,y,z]=[998904017269185277085273031353794284116040212289837695611109983941489835589093704988991388186622694678675801115341251372324168579408658228399196411961167738670690919963926145000, 696848662704778864849921534814189787568759189381574314257836513999485226137867884158291405474966792561072542344400633562198655652729746336634372892064329545674949001632139764944825, 624112577526182444004611459704516777006330363446109066083750092060586554901979604867926337854067677311069929229067579176483147938064882951926711979800558806348199484630261688832];
ellisoncurve(e1,[x/z,y/z])

As you can see it has large height.
$(X:Y:Z) = \\
(9989040172691852770852730313537942841160402122898376956111099\\
83941489835589093704988991388186622694678675801115341251372324\\
168579408658228399196411961167738670690919963926145000:\\
69684866270477886484992153481418978756875918938157431425783651\\
39994852261378678841582914054749667925610725423444006335621986\\
55652729746336634372892064329545674949001632139764944825:\\
62411257752618244400461145970451677700633036344610906608375009\\
20605865549019796048679263378540676773110699292290675791764831\\
47938064882951926711979800558806348199484630261688832)$
